# Swift Variables and Enums in ForEach Loop for Bindings

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach, enums, binding

I have a ForEach loop in which I am displaying X amount of fields over and over again depending on user entry (i.e. they enter 5, it displays 5 iterations of these fields).

I need to be able to set the TextField, FocusState, and AccessibilityFocusState bindings for these fields dynamically. I know I have to conform the enum to CaseIterable but I can't separately define an infinite number of enum cases just in case a user enters a value outside of that in which I have configured enum cases.

I also realize that in my example I have only defined a single @State variable, but as this goes along with the question, how do you define X amount of variables when doing something like this?

Here's an example:

```
struct TestView: View {

@AccessibilityFocusState var accessFocus: AccessFocusField?
@FocusState var isFocused: Field?
@State private var field = ""

enum AccessFocusField: CaseIterable {
    case fieldName
}

enum Field: CaseIterable {
    case fieldName
}
    var body: some View {

        ForEach(1...5) { value in
            TextField("Hello World!", $field[value])
                .focused($isFocused, equals: .fieldName[value]
                .accessibilityFocused($accessFocus, equals: .fieldName[value])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create struct of all those properties and make `field` (better `fields`) as an array of that struct.

Answer (score 0):

For ForEach I would create an identifiable object, named Field with all the properties that Textfield needs. And then declare an array of that object, and use that in ForEach.